# Jquery input value if and or not working

Tags: jquery, input

I have tried to get sum of visible input textboxes values ( if value not equal to F or A)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
    $("#testbtn").click(function(){
    var total_hrs = 0;   
    $("input:text").filter(":visible").each(function(){    
    if (this.value != "F" || this.value != "A"){
        total_hrs += parseInt(this.value);    
    }    
    }); 
    alert(total_hrs);
    });

});
```

Here this.value != "F" only working. If I put both with or(||) this.value !="A", it will give me NaN.

Here is the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supun151515/k8nyE/).

Thank you,

Supun Silva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `and` condition

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testbtn").click(function () {
        var total_hrs = 0;
        $("input:text").filter(":visible").each(function () {
            if (this.value != "F" && this.value != "A") {
                total_hrs += parseInt(this.value) || 0;
            }
        });
        alert(total_hrs);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gu6rJ/)

Comment: I want to know how to filter by input value, keep remaining :visible filter
Example:
`$("input:text").filter(":visible, [this.value !='F']").each(function () {
});`

This is not correct.